# How to make Vim return from insert mode to normal mode after a command is finished?

Tags: vim, command

When Vim is in Insert mode and you press Ctrl-O it switches to normal mode for one command, then switches back to insert mode when the command is finished. Is there the opposite command? To switch to insert mode for typing a word (or a number of letters or a line), then switch it back to normal mode when the typing is finished?

Comment: define "one command" in Insert mode

Comment: I'm assuming "normal mode" means "command mode."  Insert mode doesn't really make "commands."  Do you want it to switch back after inserting a key or a line or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I know of, however, if you are repeating the same operation over and over again you can fake it by using the `.` command in normal mode after you've made the change once.

An alternative (in the same scenario) would be to record a macro and run it from normal mode.